# How to only target elements with the same parent

Tags: jquery

I'm working on creating my own widgets for wordpress. I have the following code:

```
jQuery("body").on("change", "select[id=elementselect]", function(){  
    var val = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery('#element1,element2').hide().filter('#element'+val).fadeIn('slow')
})
```

The code works great but if the user has two or more widgets in the sidebar it will affect all of them. Since they are based on a class i can't give the elements in the widget unique names. So, is it possible to only target the elements which share the same parent as the "select" element i'm currenly using?

The HTML looks like this (simplified):

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <select id="elementselect">
      <option value="1"></option>
      <option value="2"></option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="element1"></fieldset>

  <fieldset id="element2"></fieldset>
</form>
```

Or is there another solution?

EDIT: I've fixed it now. Just changed the id's to classes and used .closest()

thank you all

Comment: Is this what you are needing?  http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: Possibly. But i'm not sure how to use it with .on.

Comment: Which exactly are the elements that share the same parent here?

Comment: All fieldsets are inside a form.

Comment: Fieldsets have different id. Id should be unique per page

Comment: That's not possible with widgets. I could use classes, but the question would be the same.

Comment: @John: not possible what? You **have to** give them different IDs. Change your code and modify the question

Comment: Yes, i changed it to classes and used closest(). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what your question is, but to get an elements siblings you could do this:

```
var $siblings = $('#childElement').siblings();
```

http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be helpful...

Here is a JS Fiddle example that shows how the jQuery methods `parent()`, `children()`, and `siblings()` work with events:  http://jsfiddle.net/phillipkregg/GWCyL/

The code is simple:

```
$("#parent_div p").on("click", function() {
    console.log($(this).parent().children().siblings())

});
```

Clicking a paragraph element in the div goes up to its parent - the div - and then looks for its children - the p tags - then logs the siblings of the paragraph tags.

Comment: Why did you use .parent().children().siblings() rather than just siblings() as in my answer?

Comment: You could certainly do that - I'm assuming the OP may not know how these work so I'm using all of them and giving an example where he can play around with it and learn from it.  I was also constructing my answer while you were posting yours so I never saw it.